# Generate data-widget-id (Twitter) from Account URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter

I have a widget in Wordpress, i can set Twitter actual account URL with **Widget API** input, but what about `data-widget-id`, is there any way i can convert `HTTP URL` *(http://www.twitter.com/username etc)* from twitter to `data-widget-id`, the Widgets I'm creating require that id (But i want it to generate one from Twitter Account URL).

***public function widget*** ([Wordpress Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API))

**Twitter Timeline Code**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
    href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $instance['twitter-feed-username']; ?>" 
    data-widget-id="I NEED THIS TO BE GENERATED FROM THE URL"
    data-chrome="nofooter"
    data-tweet-limit="<?php echo $instance['twitter-feed-count']; ?>"
    >Tweets by <?php echo $instance['twitter-feed-username']; ?>
</a>
```

***Closest Solution i solved by myself:***
Go to Section: **Overriding Timeline Selection** ([Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines))
Lets say if i try to put `data-screen-name="twitter"`, well this will solve the problem, but if wordpress admin remove the username from Widget section it will bring the feed from `data-widget-id`, is there a way to hack `data-widget-id`, Since this is Production Project i can't use this method.

Thank you everyone is Advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#timeline-selection):

> ### Overriding Timeline Selection
>
> ...
>
> You should configure a timeline widget from your settings page as normal.

So, `data-widget-id` is something that is provided by Twitter when you create a widget inside your profile.

To have a fallback solution:

1. Log in to your Twitter account
2. [Create a widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new) and get the provided ID
3. Write down that ID - into the widget settings or directly to the 'widget.php' file.
4. Use the `data-screen-name` attribute to override the default content of the widget.